# Fees connected with SO account

Tags: payment

I have read the Conditions of use and it's not entirely clear for me.
Are there any fees/payments just for being a normal, registered user of Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean as a simple enthusiastic programmer?
Under the FAQ for programmers, it states "How much does a profile cost?"
 - There is no charge to programmers wanting a profile. The system is entirely paid for by employers.

So assuming you simply want to use this as a helping hand, there shouldnt be any fees what so ever.

Comment: I mean just using SO as a forum, asking questions and giving answers. So probably you just answered my question. Thanks !

Comment: Mark it as an answer so others have an answer to go for, even though its right there - in the ToS / FAQ